# Cassandra trigger to Kafka on TTL expire

Tags: cassandra, triggers, spring-kafka

I'm trying to implement a trigger on Cassandra to catch delete operations on TTL expire by implementing

public Collection augment(Partition partition)
on ITrigger interface.

But event is not triggering to kafka on ttl expire.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in Cassandra as a trigger on the data expiration... TTL is just a timestamp associated with piece of data that is used when reading the data, or performing compaction to decide if this piece of data will be included into result set, or written into a new SSTable.